# Issue with loading rails seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to load some seed data into my rails application and its giving one error I don't understand. Below is my `seed.rb` file and the terminal output above it.
[image]

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: It looks like the method `create_todo_list` does not exist on your `User` model

Comment: @TomKadwill but I thought it should exist since each user has at least a todolist. Otherwise why does `create_profile` work?

Comment: please don't post text as images...

Comment: Okay @DanCornilescu, pls zoom the image and see the code. I will paste real code next time

Comment: You can edit this question as well and make it SO-worthy. You'll get a badge for it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is that you don't have a singular `todo_list` association in your `User` model, thus calling `create_todo_list` won't work.

> - When using `belongs_to` / `has_one`, you can call [`create_singular_association`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord%2FAssociations%2FClassMethods%3Abelongs_to)
> - When using `has_many`, you have to call [`collection.create`](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/4.1.7/ActiveRecord%2FAssociations%2FClassMethods%3Ahas_many)

Thus, you'll need the following in your `db/seeds.rb`:

```
#27 todo  = duser.todo_lists.create list_name: "List", list_due_date: Date.today + 1.year
#28 items = todo.todo_items.create todolistiems
```

--

This is assuming you have the following models:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :todo_lists
   has_many :todo_list_items, through: :todo_lists
end

#app/models/todo_list.rb
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
   has_many   :todo_list_items
end
```

Comment: Nice work! If it worked properly, you may wish to consider accepting the answer as to avoid confusion